# How to add multiple configurable products add to cart with size and color options in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, multiple-add-to-cart

I am trying to add to the cart multiple configurable products with color and size options.

when adding configurable products (with any children) product prices are displayed correctly only in the first configurable product... the others show price 0$

when adding different children of same configurable product only the first is being added to cart (with qtys of others being added to that first child).

Can you lead me to the error in the controller code, or any missing code required to be added?

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class AddToCart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
     */
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $cart;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;    
    protected $formKey;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $productId = isset($params['product']) ? (int)$params['product'] : 0;
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            if($productId > 0 && isset($params['options']) && !empty($params['options'])){
                $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
                foreach ($params['options'] as $option) {
                    $options = array(
                        $option['color_attribute_id'] => $option['color_option_id'],
                        $option['size_attribute_id'] => $option['size_option_id']
                    );
                    $params = array(
                        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                        'product' => $productId,
                        'super_attribute' => $options,
                        'qty' => $option['qty']
                    );
                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                    
                }
                $this->cart->save();
                $response = array(
                    'status'=> 'success',
                    'message'=>__('Items added to cart.')
                );
            }else{
                $response = array(
                    'status'=> 'error',
                    'message'=>__('No items found, please try again.')
                );  
            }
        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                'status'=> 'error',
                'message'=>$e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }    
}
```